# Problem in Serialization java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, serialization

I have a problem in serialization.

This is my DTO class:

```
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class ChoicesResponseDTO extends ResponseDTO {

    private Long idR;
    private ChoicesResponseType choicesResponseType;
    private QuestionDTO questionDTO;
}
```

and this is my scheme from swagger:

```
ChoicesResponseDTO{
    type    string
    idR integer($int64)
    choicesResponseType stringEnum:
    Array [ 3 ]
    questionDTO QuestionDTO{
         idQ    integer($int64)
         contentQ   string
         ordreQ integer($int32)
    }
}
```

The problem that if I want to add a new ChoicesDTO, it asks me to add a whole new question in it but I just want to add only the id of the question.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Lombok annotations @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor generates constructors for you:

```
public ChoicesResponseDTO(Long idR, ChoicesResponseType choicesResponseType, QuestionDTO questionDTO)

public ChoicesResponseDTO();
```

If you want :

```
public ChoicesResponseDTO(Long idR)
```

code it yourself or set idR as NonNull or final and add `@RequiredArgsConstructor` to your class (not compatible with `@NoArgsConstructor` I guess).

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that I want the scheme to be like this ```ChoicesResponseDTO{
    type    string
    idR integer($int64)
    choicesResponseType stringEnum:
    Array [ 3 ]
    idQ integer($int64);
   
} ```

Comment: I think that you have to write an other DTO with an Id instead of full Question

Comment: Well that's the problem of mapping between a DTO and id. I tried with modelMapper but didn't work.